# Same file with differente size fprintf on linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems, eof

I can't understand how EOF works and HOW does my pc know the size of a file.

For example I made 3 files, test0, test1 and test2.
I created test0 and test1 in this way:

```
int main(void) {

    /* */
    FILE* fp0 = fopen("/home/kevin/eclipse-workspaceC/FileMangment/src/test0", "w+");
    FILE* fp1 = fopen("/home/kevin/eclipse-workspaceC/FileMangment/src/test1", "w+");


    if (!fp0 || !fp1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "file pointer points to NULL\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(fp0, "abcd");
    fprintf(fp1, "abcd\n");

    fclose(fp0);
    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I created test2 with, right click -> new documents and inside the file I wrote:

```
abcd
```

Without a space nor a new line at the end.
Then on the bash I ran the command: `wc -c test*; file test*`
and the output:

```
4 test0
5 test1
5 test2
14 total
test0: ASCII text, with no line terminators
test1: ASCII text
test2: ASCII text
```

When I go to watch the files with gedit they seems identical(no new lines founded).

I know that `\n` is newline and not EOF (And I really can't understand what is this this EOF), so HOW does my pc know when the file ends? If the disk block size is 4K why does it stop after the correct number of bytes and it does not continue to read whatever is comes after?

Why do I see tons of codes that parses a file in this way:

```
while((c=fgetc(infile))!=EOF){
putchar(c);
}
```

So this MEANS that there is SOMEWHERE a character called (EOF)???????
But I can't find it in ascii table. And I found that is value is -1....
Very very very confusing...

Is my pc parsing every file for know is size or it's written somewhere?

Somewhere in my computer the must be:

```
your file at position xyz has the size of blahblah...
```

So WHERE is this place? or what should I google?
Because I Googled something like 3Gozzilion of things like: where is my file size stored ecc... and did't find anything. I Just want to know where is this information stored.

Comment: The file information in the filesystem has the actual size of the file (bytes in use). The I/O library and/or OS use this to limit what you can read from the file.

Comment: There is no character that is an`EOF`. `fgetc` doesn't return a `char`. It returns a character promoted to `int` or `EOF` on end of file.

Comment: "so HOW does my pc know when the file ends?"  The file length, time of creation/modificaiton, file name, etc are stored elsewhere.  This meta data is often in stored in the folder/directory.

Comment: Hint: "I see tons of codes" ...  and `c=fgetc(infile)`.  What is the type returned by `fgetc()`?  Why is that type _not_ `char`?

Comment: Start reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system

Comment: `file pointer points to NULL` is not really useful error message. Check the error condition after *each* `fopen` and exit printing the error message with `perror`, or use `strerror`!

Comment: @chux the metadata is *never* stored in a *folder*, except on totally broken file systems such as FAT.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala LOL.  But I wouldn't call FAT *totally* broken - it does have some advantages.  Finding and reading a file can be done quickly, which is good for things like embedded systems with limited memory and thus no way to cache a lot of filesystem metadata.

Comment: @AndrewHenle FAT is dreadfully bad for everything else except read-only flash file systems, and for read-only flash file systems it is just too complicated :D No, FAT is notoriously known as the design where you *absolutely must* cache lots of metadata on magnetic disks for fast accesses.

Comment: immediately after each call to `fopen()`   need to check (!=NULL) the returned value and if NULL, then call `perror()` so the reason the call failed is output on `stderr`

Comment: for a proper understanding of how the file system is laid out on (for instance) a hard disk requires way more room than available here.  However, in general, the disk is divided into cylinders that are divided in sectors The number of cylinders and the size of each sector varies depending on the size of the disk storage and other factors.  In general, each sector has an 'inode' number.  some inodes are used to store the directory entries.  Each of those directory entries has the inode number of the start of the related file or the inode number of the start of the sub directory....

Comment: *So this MEANS that there is SOMEWHERE a character called (EOF)*   No, what this means is the function (in this case: `fgetc()`) returned a status that contains -1 rather than contains the next byte from the input file.  Way down in the OS or kernel or whereever, it recognized that no more characters were available from that file so announced that condition by returning -1 (EOF)

Comment: If you really want to see what is on the disk, then need to use a utility that displays the raw disk data as actually stored on the disk. (some text editors can be placed in 'hex' mode and will then show each of the characters stored in a file but not the disk formatting characters. You can lookup the HEX characters in an ASCII table such as at: `http://www.asciitable.com/` to know just what they are

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX each file corresponds to an inode number of the file system. In that inode you can find several information about the file, including the file size. You can find more information here :
[Overview of the Linux file system](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html)

Answer (score 0):

On a unix system when you issue a command like

```
ls -l
```

the output is something similar to this

```
-rw-r--r--    1 user group       393 Nov  3 22:02 README.txt
```

this includes file permissions, owner, group size, created time, file name etc etc etc.

at a file system level this information is stored in an inode viz a structure representing the file meta-data, infact each file itself is represented by an inode number.

at a very high level every read call increments the cursor-position to read bytes. and at some point this will reach size of file. in which case read call may not even return the requested number of files. for example

observe this read call below, where we are trying to read size number of bytes from file represented by file descriptor fd.

```
int nbytes = read( fd, buf, size );
```

however it is perfectly possible that nbytes can be < size in which case most of the times next subsequent read call may fail with EOF ( if end of file is reached) . however there are other scenarios as well where nbytes may not be equal to size.